# How to solve owl carousel not working in angularjs template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slide, owl-carousel

I am trying to load an owl-carousel slider in an angularJs partial template but it does not display the slides. It works fine when loaded in a HTML page but does not work in the template. Any suggestion on how I can solve this:

**HTML PAGE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="main">
    <head>
        <title>Woodworld</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="data/images/css/all.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layoutstyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:500px)" href="styles/medium-screens.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width:1050px)" href="styles/large-screens.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/owl.theme.default.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/owl.carousel.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/owl.theme.green.min.css">
        <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/modules.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/wow.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <div ng-view>
        </div>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/stylescript.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Template code:**

```
<div owl-carousel class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><h2>Slide 1</h2></div>
    <div class="item"><h2>Slide 2</h2></div>
    <div class="item"><h2>Slide 3</h2></div>
    <div class="item"><h2>Slide 4</h2>Slide </div>
</div>
```

**OWL Carousel directive code:**

```
app.directive("owlCarousel", owlCarouselDirective);
function owlCarouselDirective() {
  return {
    restrict  : "A",
    transclude: false,
    link      : function ($scope, element, attributes) {
      $scope.initCarousel = function () {
        $(element).owlCarousel($scope.HomeVM.owlDefaultOpts);
      };
    }
  };
}
function owlCarouselItemDirective() {
    return {
      restrict  : "A",
      transclude: false,
      link      : function ($scope, element, attributes) {
        if ( $scope.$last )
          $scope.initCarousel();
      }
    };
}
```

Comment: @georgeawg would you help me solve this.

Comment: It doesn't show any error on the console. It works fine but fails to load in template view but works fine when included in a full HTML page.